# PHPStorm not reacting to break points

Tags: php, phpstorm, xdebug

I have recently installed PHPStorm and Xdebug in order to debug PHP scripts running on a local server. I am running Mac OS 10.8.5 and MAMP. I have been using Safari 6.2.4 as my principal browser, but the issue occurs also with Initially, I was able to get PHPStorm to stop at checkpoints I have placed, but in one script, it refused to enter a `foreach() {}` statement. I therefore created a small test script which contained only this statement, and tested it on its own. First PHPStorm was happy to step through each line, and then it refused to stop at any breakpoints at all, either in my small test script or in any other script.

I have spent several hours checking and rechecking the various official guides, and testing all the techniques suggested. At times, my test page will start to load, and then the progress bar in the browser will stop. I am guessing that PHPStorm is, in fact, reacting to the break point, but failing to show the debugger controls.

Here is a screenshot of this situation. Should there be another panel in the PHPStorm window, to allow me to step through the script? If so, how can I get it to appear? If not, is there any way of debugging the PHPStorm debugger?

[image: Screen shot of PHPStorm and Safari]

Here are the xdebug settings in php.ini:

```
[xdebug]
zend_extension="/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.5.3/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20121212/xdebug.so"
xdebug.remote_enable=1
xdebug.remote_host="localhost"
xdebug.remote_port="9000"
xdebug.profiler_enable=1
xdebug.profiler_output_dir="/Applications/MAMP/tmp"
xdebug.remote_log="/Applications/MAMP/logs/xdebug.log"
```

I have a Run/Debug configuration set up in PHPStorm as:

```
Host: web                          Port: 9000
Document Root: /Volumes/Sites/web
```

Here's the output of the xdebug.log:

```
Log opened at 2015-05-20 12:06:48
I: Connecting to configured address/port: localhost:9000.
I: Connected to client. :-)
-> <init xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="http://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" fileuri="file:///Volumes/Sites/web/test.php" language="PHP" protocol_version="1.0" appid="3174" idekey="1"><engine version="2.2.3"><![CDATA[Xdebug]]></engine><author><![CDATA[Derick Rethans]]></author><url><![CDATA[http://xdebug.org]]></url><copyright><![CDATA[Copyright (c) 2002-2013 by Derick Rethans]]></copyright></init>

-> <response xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="http://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" status="stopping" reason="ok"></response>

Log closed at 2015-05-20 12:06:48
```

In the Run panel, I see:

```
/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.5.3/bin/php -S jce:9000 -t /Volumes/Sites/web
[Wed May 20 08:06:48 2015] 127.0.0.1:51388 Invalid request (Malformed HTTP request)
```

The port number after `127.0.0.1:` changes each time I refresh the browser.

PHPStorm also fails to react to breakpoints set in JavaScript files running in the browser.

Comment: 1) Please provide xdebug.log http://xdebug.org/docs/all_settings#remote_log . 2) Also make sure that PhpStorm is actually listening on xdebug port (`netstat`). 3) You are debugging web script -- does debugging CLI script works?

Comment: phpInfo says: `xdebug.remote_log:  [local value]no value  [master value]no value`. Perhaps I should start by fixing that. Where do I find the xdebug configuration settings file?

Comment: It's all done in `php.ini` -- check what file is actually used by your PHP interpreter (it's in a top header of `phpinfo();` output)

Comment: Why do you run your site on `9000` port? It's the port where PhpStorm should be listening for xdebug connections and not where you run your web site ...

Comment: *"PHPStorm also fails to react to breakpoints set in JavaScript files running in the browser."* What browser? Current stable version supports Chrome only.

Comment: Have a look at the manuals in case you have not seen them yet: 1) https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/PhpStorm/Debugging+with+PhpStorm 2) https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/PhpStorm/JavaScript+Debugging+in+PhpStorm